# Who setup Jupyter Notebook in Google Cloud Dataproc cluster in free trail period?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

While following [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook) guide to setup a jupyter notebook on a Google Cloud Dataproc cluster I am getting the following error:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-name \
    --project my-project-id \
    --bucket my-bucket-name
    --initialization-actions \
    gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh

(gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Multiple validation errors:
 - Insufficient 'CPUS' quota. Requested 12.0, available 8.0.
 - This request exceeds CPU quota. Some things to try: request fewer workers (a minimum of 2 is required), use smaller master and/or worker machine types (such as n1-standard-2).
```

I am in the free trais period and restricted to [8-cpus](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/free-trial-quotas). How can I change the machine type? What setup would you recommend?

Comment: I tried `--master-machine-type  n1-highmem-8`, same error.

Comment: Hey! Remember that workers are created when you run this command, too. Try using `--worker-machine-type n1-highmem-4` and use `n1-highmem-4` for your master machine, too.

Answer (score 2):

The default will have the minimum 2 workers (due to HDFS replication requirements) plus a master node, and the default machine type is n1-standard-4. Since you only have 8 available cores, you need:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-name \
    --project my-project-id \
    --bucket my-bucket-name \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are following along with the post "GOOGLE CLOUD BIG DATA AND MACHINE LEARNING BLOG" (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/02/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-jupyter-notebooks-with-apache-spark-on-google-cloud), you have to modify a little on @Dennis Huo's solution,

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create datascience \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh
```

because you will get error on setting project and bucket.

Note:
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Not allowed to get project settings for project my-project-id

ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Access denied for Google Cloud Storage bucket: 'my-bucket-name')

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the project info. Follow an example:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTERNAME \
    --project $PROJECT \
    --num-workers $WORKERS \
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --master-machine-type $VMMASTER \
    --worker-machine-type $VMWORKER \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
    --scopes cloud-platform
```